# mysql_insert_id() returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, return, mysql-insert-id

I know there are a lot of topics with the same title. But mostly it's the query that's been inserted in the wrong place. But I think I placed it right. 
So the problem is, that I still get 0 even when the data is inserted in the db. 
Does someone knows an answer where I could be wrong?

here's my code:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
    $this->arr_kolommen = $arr_kolommen;
    $this->arr_waardes = $arr_waardes;
    $this->tabel = $tabel;
    $aantal = count($this->arr_kolommen);
    //$sql="INSERT INTO `tbl_photo_lijst_zoekcriteria` ( `PLZ_FOTO` , `PLZ_ZOEKCRITERIA`,`PLZ_CATEGORIE`)VALUES ('$foto', '$zoekje','$afdeling');";
    $insert = "INSERT INTO ".$this->tabel." ";
    $kolommen = "(";
    $waardes = " VALUES(";
    for($i=0;$i<$aantal;$i++)
    {
        $kolommen .=$this->arr_kolommen[$i].",";
        $waardes .="'".$this->arr_waardes[$i]."',";
    }
    $kolommen = substr($kolommen,0,-1).")";
    $waardes = substr($waardes,0,-1).")";
    $insert .=$kolommen.$waardes;   
    $result = mysql_query($insert,$this->db)  or die ($this->sendErrorToMail(str_replace("  ","",str_replace("\r\n","\n",$insert))."\n\n".str_replace(" ","",str_replace("\r\n","\n",mysql_error()))));
    $waarde = mysql_insert_id();
```

Thanks a lot in advance, because I have been breaking my head for this one for almost already a whole day. (and probably it's something small and stupid)

Comment: please show the table scheme. Do you have a auto increment table field?

Comment: You're using a specific link identifier in your query ($this->db), but not for the insert_id. That could cause it to look to a whole other connection.
"If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed."

Comment: @ Topener: Yes I have auto increment table field.  ID  Int(11)  Nee  Geen  AUTO_INCREMENT      @PtPazuzu and how could I solve the problem?  (Thank you both for answeringà

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) mysql_insert_id returns:

> The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on
>   success, **0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   value**, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

Since it does not give you `false` and not the correct number it indicates that the queried table didn't generate an auto-increment value.

There are two possibilities I can think of:

1. Your table doesn't have an auto_increment field
2. Since you doesn't provide the link to the mysql_insert_id() but using a link with mysql_query() it might not be the correct table that's queried when retrieving the last inserted id.

Solution:

1. Make sure it has an auto_increment field
2. Provide the link aswell: `$waarde = mysql_insert_id($this->db);`

Comment: The ID is an auto_increment field. But how could I solve it, if it's the 2nd problem?

Comment: @user750079 try call `mysql_insert_id` with `$this->db` as I've mentioned in the answer

Comment: @ Marcus Sorry I overread it. But it worked. Thank you very much. I was so stupid to write instead of $this->db ; $insert, $result (with other words, all other vars, but forgot the $this). Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by $this->db? my code is this:
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (myColumn) values ('myValue');");
  $id = mysql_insert_id();

Comment: Please give the resource name also in case you get 0. eg. mysql_insert_id($connection)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your INSERT query was not successful - e.g., maybe you were trying to insert duplicate data on a column whose data must be unique?

Answer (score 0):

If the id is indeed set to auto increment and still get '0' as your response do a column and value count i experienced this only later on I noticed a number of my column count did not match values count.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has an odd behaviourd when calling mysql_insert_id(). The function returns 0 after the first call. So calling it twice will return 0.

Use a variable instead of calling the function more times:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```