# get primary key to put as foreign key in other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, what I want to do is to get the primary key lastly inserted into the user table and then put that into the foreign key of the library table. I don't know how to do it with $request or what to do here?

```
public function register($request = array()) {
    $data = array(
        'user_name' => $request['username'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
        'email' => ($request['email']) 
    );
    $data1 = array(
        'user_id' => '5',// this is where I have to put the primary key from last table
        'library_name' => $request['lib_name']
    );

    $this->model->insert('user', $data);
    $this->model->insert('library', $data1);
    $this->redirect('uploadSongs.php');
}
```

Comment: Do you have a mysql storage engine that supports foreign keys? (InnoDB?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
public function register($request = array()) {
    $data = array(
        'user_name' => $request['username'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
        'email' => ($request['email']) 
    );

    $this->model->insert('user', $data);
   $user_id = $this->model->select('user', $data); //select user_id from db 
   $data1 = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id ,
        'library_name' => $request['lib_name']
    );



    $this->model->insert('library', $data1);
    $this->redirect('uploadSongs.php');
}
```

Comment: this is not the optimized way of doing that. there is a function of mysql_insert_id() why not utillize that

Comment: thanks poonam your idea was helpful, just a little change I just had to get ID from mysql_insert_id() as Faizan said than using select query... thanks u all, after all its working :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysql_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html)

> -- Returns the value generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous INSERT or UPDATE statement.

Comment: shall it work if I have indexed the foreign key of second table and applied cascade on delete and update?

Comment: read about it dear.. see this link for example.. 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_insert_id.asp

Comment: thanks but m doing the same thing, still it's generating '0' result!

Comment: ok ok.. this is what you are looking for..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243503/mysql-insert-id-returns-0

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
public function register($request = array()) {
$data = array(
    'user_name' => $request['username'],
    'password' => $request['password'],
    'email' => ($request['email']) 
);
$data1 = array(
    'library_name' => $request['lib_name']
);

$this->model->insert('user', $data);
$user_id = mysql_insert_id();
$data1['userid'] = $user_id;
$this->model->insert('library', $data1);
$this->redirect('uploadSongs.php');
```

}
If you are using any frameworks. then they have the helper functions to get last insert id, you should use them

Comment: what do i have to do with $user_id = mysql_inser_id(); here while I need that in about at $data1 = array('user_id' => //here)

Comment: well you need to build the array before it is being sent to insert.I am dynamizally adding the element to array you see after where I get userid

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, it worked all i needed to do was just to change the logic, I was using it stupidly and didn't see where to place the insert query so Its working now all i had to do was just to change the place of the insert query as given

```
public function register($request = array()) {
$data = array(
    'user_name' => $request['username'],
    'password' => $request['password'],
    'email' => ($request['email']) 
);

$this->model->insert('user', $data);
$data1 = array(
    'user_id' => mysql_insert_id(),// now it works as insert has been done above .... 
    'library_name' => $request['lib_name']
);
$this->model->insert('library', $data1);
$this->redirect('uploadSongs.php');
```