# Why is MySQL not returning the last inserted id, it returns 0?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, opencart

I have a table that has a primary key that autoincrements. Everytime I insert a row to that table, and use `mysql_insert_id()` to get the last id inserted for that table, it returns 0.

What other possible problems could there be?

Comment: Is the insert actually happening? Chances are the query is failing so there is no id to return.

Comment: interestingly enough, the row is getting inserted...

Comment: This can't be answered without seeing code. Some other query process or connection closure could be interfering, or any number of things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243503/mysql-insert-id-returns-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the method that [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/) provides:

```
$this->db->getLastId()
```

Comment: ya i used that originally, but it was getting the same error i described above.

Comment: And you were using INSERT and the $this->db->query function? Also, does this issue occur when you insert a new product/category? If not, then it's either db design or you are simply not using the methods correctly. As pointed out by others a code sample would be easy enough to validate this