# Why is mysqli_insert_id returning me 0

Tags: php, mysql

I actually read an answer here, the user says this happens when your table is not having any `autoincrement` column but am already having that, the other is connection is not established, but when I used this

```
if(!$running_db) {
    echo 'False';
} else {
    echo 'true'; //Returns me true so connection is establised
}
```

Than why it is returning me `0`? Actually am inserting on `page.php` and after successfully inserted user is redirected to `result.php` page where I am echoing out the id using `mysqli_insert_id` so that I can highlight the field but it returns me 0 and the table row is thus failing to highlight

P.S Am using procedural way

Comment: You need to show us your `INSERT` query, as well as your call to `mysql_insert_id`, and it's also probably helpful to include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` so we can see what the structure of your table is. But without any of that - have you made sure the data is actually getting to your table without errors?

Comment: Post you db-related code here!

Comment: result.php is a completely new script, that has no knowledge of what has occurred in the page.php script.... mysqli_insert_id() is only aware of inserts that have taken place in the script where it is called.... call mysqli_insert_id() in page.php, and pass the returned value to result.php

Comment: refer Marcus' answer's 2nd point [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243503/mysql-insert-id-returns-0).

Comment: @ColinMorelli The loop is dynamic, I decide the rows and column dynamically, table is perfect, insert works perfectly, no errors but `mysql_insert_id` returns me `0`

Comment: @MarkBaker So should I save the data in a session and destroy it later?

Comment: @AcidicCloud Didn't even catch that part of the question. Insert IDs are tracked on a per-connection basis and each new page load establishes a new connection. This means that after opening `result.php` the insert ID is no longer available.

Comment: @Acidic - session is probably the safest way of passing the result

Comment: @ColinMorelli Cool, so I store the value in a session and unset it after use right?

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you very much, will use it for highlight, and will unset it after I've used it :)

Comment: show us your `$running_db` how is defined

Comment: @echo_me party's over ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you redirect to the new script you loose that information. Without seeing your code, all I can advice is to reat the `mysqli_insert_id` in the `page.php` script, save it in a SESSION variable and then redirect to `result.php` where you check that SESSION variable and find the saved id in it.

Comment: Ya, actually I decided the solution by reading comments :) thanks anyways will mark the answer as correct as soon as system allows me

Answer (score 2):

Note from the php manual :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

"Because mysql_insert_id() acts on the last performed query, be sure to call mysql_insert_id() immediately after the query that generates the value. "

Retrieve the value on the same page, place it in session and then access the value from the session variable on any other page.