# mysql_insert_id(); / last_insert_id(); isn't returning latest ID without any known issue

Tags: php, mysql

`mysql_insert_id(); / last_insert_id();`  isn't returning latest ID without any known issue

```
$insert = "INSERT into `table` (`name`,`address`) VALUES ('$name', '$address')";                    mysql_select_db($database_A, $A);
$result = mysql_query($insert,$A) or die mysql_error();
$latest_id = mysql_insert_id($A); 
var_dump($latest_id);
```

According to `PHP` manual I see any reason in the code why it's not returning the latest `ID`, instead it's always returning `NULL` or `0`. It's happening in case of `last_insert_id();` too.

`This function returns 0 if the previous operation does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT ID, or FALSE on MySQL connection failure.`

Any idea?

Comment: And data is inserted fine?

Comment: Why do you people still using deprecated API? Just read the first sentence of http://us2.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php Also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243503/mysql-insert-id-returns-0

Comment: try mysql_insert_id() without the connection variable $A it actually uses the last opened connection if connection is not specified so anyways $A is redundant.

Comment: Please check if your table schema has an auto_increment() id field.

Comment: @ Hanky 웃 Panky, yes data are inserted properly along with auto_incremented id.