# mysql_insert_id($result) not returning ID

Tags: php, mysql

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO primarySkills (primaryName) VALUES $surveySQL";
$result = mysql_query($SQL) or die ('Cannot execute query...'.$SQL);
$surveyID = mysql_insert_id($result);
```

The above code will enter the table data correctly (primaryID, primaryName) but not return the `id` generated using `mysql_insert_id()`. Please let me know why the `id` is not returned?

What is really odd is that I use this function twice before in the same script for different tables and it works there.  I double checked that primaryID is auto_increment and a primary key.

Blessings!

Comment: Are you sure that insert statement actually works? Looks problematic to me.

Comment: Please [stop using mysql_functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) as they were removed from PHP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_insert\_id() returns 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243503/mysql-insert-id-returns-0)

Comment: This is very unusual and I have reviewed the other mysql_insert_id() and this problem is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using pdo since MYSQL functions have been removed as of php 7. I did not test your sql command. replace these values:

```
localhost: your host
3306: your port if different
dbname: the name of your database
root: your username
'': the last parameter is your password.

<?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=testdb', 'root', '');
$conn->SetAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );   
$SQL = "INSERT INTO primarySkills (primaryName) VALUES (:test)";
$insert = $conn->prepare($sql);
$insert->bindValue(":test", $surveySQL, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->execute();
$last_insert_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
?>
```

When you have completed testing and are ready to go into production, go ahead and remove this line of code:

```
$conn->SetAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  When I changed to mysqli then I could use $conn in the mysqli_insert_id otherwise I had to leave the mysql_insert_id empty.

Comment: If this was the right answer, please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I did accept it!  Both answers were right.  Yours was more right because I should migrate to mysqli.

Comment: There is check mark under the up or down vote. Please press that.

Answer (score 2):

**Stop using mysql functions**
However the problem in your case could be primaryID is not a autoincrement  and probably also not a primary key. For mysql_insert_id() to work, there should be a autoincrement column. Also change the query.

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO primarySkills (primaryName) VALUES ($surveySQL)";
```

and try using mysql_insert_id() instead of mysql_insert_id($result).

Comment: It is auto_increment and a primary key

Comment: just try using mysql_insert_id()

Comment: This was also the correct answer.  However, because it is best for me to change to mysqli I checked the mysqli answer.